# jQuery on() not working on loaded elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

Im doing everything like said in documents but it just isn't firing.

```
    //Magnific Popup Background Blur

    $('a.video-popup').on('click', function(e) {

        $('.main-wrapper').addClass('blur');
        $('header').addClass('blur');

        console.log('Easy!');

    });

    $('document.body').on('click','.mfp-wrap', function(e) {  //mfp-wrap is background

        console.log('Finallly!!');

        $('.main-wrapper').removeClass('blur');
        $('header').removeClass('blur');
    });
```

First function works very well but the second one..

**Situation:**

- If a.video-popup is pressed, popup appears with background
- Popup elements are not in DOM when page is loaded
- Popup elements are directly under body if loaded
- If background is clicked, popup closes
- I get nothing - doesn't remove classes or give consol.log, also no errors

---

### **SOLUTION:**

```
$('document.body').on('click','.mfp-wrap', function(e)
```

to

```
$(document).on('click','.mfp-wrap', function(e)
```

Comment: Can include `html` at Question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this selector

```
$('document.body')
```

means `document` node which contain `body` class not `body` node

and there is no node which name is `document`

Try like this

```
$(document).on('click','.mfp-wrap', function(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting

`$(document.body).on('click','.mfp-wrap'`

for

`$('document.body').on('click','.mfp-wrap'`

Comment: Can include `html` at Question ? , create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?